# OpenSSL 1.1.1f measure the speed of SHA3 series

Tags: ubuntu, speed, openssl, hashing

In my Ubuntu `OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020` is installed. I can measure the SHA256 speed by

`$ openssl speed sha256`

Help list the following as message digest commands

```
Message Digest commands (see the `dgst' command for more details)
blake2b512        blake2s256        gost              md4               
md5               rmd160            sha1              sha224            
sha256            sha3-224          sha3-256          sha3-384          
sha3-512          sha384            sha512            sha512-224        
sha512-256        shake128          shake256          sm3
```

When I try to measure the speed of sha3-512 with

`$ openssl  speed sha3-512` I've got an error;

`speed: Unknown algorithm sha3-512`

Is there a way to measure the speed of the SHA3 series in my setup?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the most recent release OpenSSL 1.1.1i?

Comment: I don't think that Ubuntu has such a package, so I need to upgrade by compile like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44789238/1820553)

Comment: I just assumed (incorrectly) it was due to partial TLS 1.3 support

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use the "evp" flag:

```
$ openssl speed -evp sha3-512
```

OpenSSL has traditionally provided 2 mechanisms to run algorithms. One is via low level APIs, and one is via the generic "EVP" interface. OpenSSL is moving towards only providing algorithms via "EVP". Algorithms that were more recently added to OpenSSL are only available via "EVP" and do not have low level APIs at all. In the forthcoming OpenSSL 3.0, all the old low-level APIs for algorithms are deprecated.